# Scrapy: getting an item using XPath

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to extract this text `This is it` from the following html code:

```
 <span id="theId" class="theClass1 nUl" title="This is it" >
```

I am trying this:

```
response.xpath('//span[@class="theClass1 nUl"]')
```

But I do not know how to get what is inside `title`.
How can I do that?

Comment: in the HTML code that I have it doesn't have the closing character `/` at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this XPath expression to get the text content of the `title` attribute:

```
response.xpath('//span[@class="theClass1 nUl"]/@title')
```

Output is:

```
This is it
```

Comment: Thanks, how do I actually get the output? do I need to add .extract() or something?

Comment: Ok I guess I need to make it as: `response.xpath('//span[@class="theClass1 nUl"]/@title').extract_first()`